# Получить массив как результат обработки запроса mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server, функции, запрос

Я написал небольшой скрипт который работает с mssql модулем. После обработки ответа отдает массив с массивами строк. но внутри функции. данный массив мне нужен на выходе из функции mssqlQuery().Помогите вывести его. Не могу сообразить как это сделать. отнеситесь с пониманием, я новичек. Ниже код:

```js
var sql = require('mssql');
var serv = "mssql://abs:abc@10.73.108.16:1433/TEST2";
var sqlQuery = 'select * from data';

function mssqlQuery(serv, sqlQuery) {
    sql.connect(serv)
        .then(function() {
            //query
            new sql.Request().query(sqlQuery)
                .then(function(recordset) {
                    var arr = [];
                    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
                        arr[n] = valuesToArray(recordset.recordset[n]);

                    // I want to get this 'arr' as a result of the work of the mssqlQuery()
                    console.dir(arr);
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    // ... query error check
                });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.dir(err);
        });
}

function valuesToArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) { return obj[key]; });
}
mssqlQuery(serv, sqlQuery);
```